# WrappedComponent not working inside async function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have HOC component that wraps certain pages in my NextJS React frontend app. Inside this HOC I am performing some JWT token validation and in case it is invalid, I am making a call to the backend to get a new Access Token (my Refresh Token is stored inside httpOnly cookie). The code used to work before, because I did not have a callback function inside my `jwt.verify` method for the case when token is expired(did not have refresh token functionality in my backend). Why the `return <WrappedComponent {...props} />` is not working?

**with_auth_client.js**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const withAuthClient = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const getNewToken = async() => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const server_path = process.env.SERVER_ADDRESS;
    const res = await fetch(`${server_path}/api/v1/external/client/newToken`, {
      method: 'get',
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    if(res.status === 403){
      router.push('/signin');
    }else{
      const newAccessToken = await JSON.parse(res);
      console.log("New access Token generated ", newAccessToken);
      window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', newAccessToken);
    }
  }

  return (props) => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
      const router = useRouter();
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
      if(accessToken === null){
        router.push('/signin');
        return null;
      }
      console.log(accessToken)
      const data = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_DATA_HASH_TOKEN, async (err, user) => {
        if(err && err.name === "TokenExpiredError"){
          console.log("TokenExpiredError ---> ");
          await getNewToken();
        }
        else{
          console.log("User is ", user);
          if(user.role !== 'client'){
            router.push('/signin');
            return null;
          }else{
            console.log("Return WrappedComponent --> ");
            return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
          }
        }
      });
      console.log("We are seeing data -> , but we should not be here", data);       
    }    
    return null;
  }
}

export default withAuthClient;
```

### Edit

#### My solution is the following

I am totally aware that the solution is not the best, but it works. I welcome any improvement suggestions.

```
return (props) => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
      const router = useRouter();
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
      if(accessToken === null){
        router.push('/signin');
        return null;
      }
      console.log(accessToken)
      const data = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_DATA_HASH_TOKEN); 
      if(data && data.name === "TokenExpiredError"){
        console.log("TokenExpiredError ---> ");
        getNewToken();
        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      }
      else{
        console.log("User is ", data);
        if(data.role !== 'client'){
          router.push('/signin');
          return null;
        }else{
          console.log("Return WrappedComponent --> ");
          return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        }
      }     
    }    
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: But do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Camilo It directs to the next page and the next page should be doing some calls inside the useEffect. However, api calls inside the useEffect are not working.. Basically, even just rendering <h1>Hello </h1> is not display..

Comment: @Camilo I added how my previous file looked like and it was working. Though the true functionality of the Component was not finished yet.

Comment: Maybe try awaiting `jwt.verify()` instead of passing a callback?

Comment: @Camilo I went ahead with using jwt.verify synchronous method. The solution looks hacky to me, but works. ``` await jwt.verify``` is not working inside not async function. Which means that I will need to change the return function to be async. In that case NextJS was throwing an error.